# picocli example showing the usage of multiple commands

Tags: picocli

ive got some code that works very well with picocli:

```
 @Command(name = "parse", sortOptions = false, description = "parse input files and write to database")
class CommandLineArgumentParser {


@Option(names = { "-h", "--help" }, usageHelp = true, description = "display this message")
private boolean helpRequested = false;


@Option(names = { "-s", "--startDate"}, description = "First day at which to parse data",
        converter = GermanDateConverter.class, paramLabel = "dd.MM.yyyy")
public LocalDate start;

@Option(names = { "-e", "--endDate"}, description = "Last day (inclusive) at which to stop parsing",
        converter = GermanDateConverter.class, paramLabel = "dd.MM.yyyy")
public LocalDate end;


private static class GermanDateConverter implements ITypeConverter<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String value) throws Exception {
        LocalDate result = null;

            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
            result = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
            if (result.getYear() < 1900) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("year should be after 1900");
            }
        return result;
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    CommandLineArgumentParser commandlineparser = new CommandLineArgumentParser();

    CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(commandlineparser);
    try {
        commandLine.parseArgs(args);

    } catch (MissingParameterException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println();
        CommandLine.usage(CommandLineArgumentParser.class, System.out);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (ParameterException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println();
        CommandLine.usage(CommandLineArgumentParser.class, System.out);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    if (commandLine.isUsageHelpRequested()) {
        commandLine.usage(System.out);
        return;
    } else if (commandLine.isVersionHelpRequested()) {
        commandLine.printVersionHelp(System.out);
        return;
    }

    if (commandlineparser.start == null) {
        log.warn("no start date specified, using: 01.01.2005");
        commandlineparser.start = LocalDate.of(2005, 01, 01);
    }

    if (commandlineparser.end == null) {
        LocalDate timePoint = LocalDate.now();
        log.warn("no end date specified, using today: " + timePoint.toString());
        commandlineparser.end = timePoint;
    }
}
```

but i did not find a simple example that shows multiple commands used, for example this one:
https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/src/test/java/picocli/Demo.java

does not compile:

```
int exitCode = new CommandLine(new Demo()).execute(args);

The method execute(CommandLine, List<Object>) in the type CommandLine is not applicable for the    arguments (String[])
```

could somebody please post a example on howto use multiple commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you’re using an older version of the library. The `execute(String []) : int` method was introduced in picocli 4.0.

Upgrading and using the [`execute`](https://picocli.info/#execute) method instead of the `parseArgs` method will allow you to remove a lot of boilerplate code from the application: handling requests for usage/version help and dealing with invalid input is done automatically with the `execute` method.

Your commands should implement Runnable or Callable, and this is where the business logic of each command lives.

Modifying your example and giving it a [subcommand](https://picocli.info/#_subcommands):

```java
@Command(name = "parse", sortOptions = false,
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = “1.0”,
        description = "parse input files and write to database",
        subcommands = MySubcommand.class)
class CommandLineArgumentParser implements Callable<Integer> {

    @Option(names = { "-s", "--startDate"}, description = "First day at which to parse data",
            converter = GermanDateConverter.class, paramLabel = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    public LocalDate start;

    @Option(names = { "-e", "--endDate"}, description = "Last day (inclusive) at which to stop parsing",
            converter = GermanDateConverter.class, paramLabel = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    public LocalDate end;


    private static class GermanDateConverter implements ITypeConverter<LocalDate> {
        @Override
        public LocalDate convert(String value) throws Exception {
            LocalDate result = null;

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                result = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
                if (result.getYear() < 1900) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("year should be after 1900");
                }
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        if (start == null) {
            log.warn("no start date specified, using: 01.01.2005");
            start = LocalDate.of(2005, 01, 01);
        }

        if (end == null) {
            LocalDate timePoint = LocalDate.now();
            log.warn("no end date specified, using today: " + timePoint.toString());
            end = timePoint;
        }

        // more business logic here ...

        // add finally return an exit code 
        int exitCode = ok ? 0 : 1;
        return exitCode;
    }
}

@Command(name = "foo")
class MySubcommand implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return 0;
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(
                CommandLineArgumentParser.class,
                new picocli.spring.PicocliSpringFactory())
                .execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
     }
}
```

Note that when using Spring in combination with picocli subcommands, you need to call the `CommandLine` constructor with a `picocli.spring.PicocliSpringFactory`.

For a more complete Spring example, see the [picocli-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-spring-boot-starter) README.

Comment: so i can run: java -jar target/jsontest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar foo - prints hi, as expected. but running with parse instead prints: Unmatched argument at index 0: 'parse' - since neither start or end are required i was expecting to see the lines: "no start date specified, using: 01.01.2005" and the other one for end...?

Comment: The example defines an `--startDate` and an `--endDate` option, and a`foo` subcommand. If you pass in an argument that doesn’t match any of these (like the string `parse`), then picocli considers this invalid input and it shows an error message. You can tell picocli to ignore such invalid arguments with the `CommandLine.setUnmatchedArgumentsAllowed` method. See https://picocli.info/#_unmatched_input . Alternatively, you can capture these arguments by defining [positional parameters](https://picocli.info/#_positional_parameters) in addition to the options.

Comment: But arent @Command(name = "parse"...) and @Command(name = "foo") defined the same way, just that parse got some parameters that could go with it?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. You are asking why the name of the top-level command doesn’t need to be specified on the command line. The idea is that you would wrap the `java -jar myjar.jar` invocation in a script named `parse`, or alternatively use GraalVM to compile your CLI app to a native image called `parse`. After that, users can invoke your program with `parse foo`. (And you don’t want to require them to type `parse parse foo`.)

Comment: exactly, thank you for that explanation and  for supporting your own software here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You’re welcome! Please star the project on GitHub if you like it.  :-)